# How to load/unload an html to a div by clicking on a button with slideDown/Up

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, slidetoggle

I am working on a big menu-list that opens/closes with jquery's toggle() function.
I would like for one of the items on the menu-list to, when clicked, slideDown and reveal load() content from another .html on the div beneath it and then, when clicked again, to slideUp and remove the load () content.

The code i have written so far seems to work, however, after clicking the second time, it seems to go "crazy" and confuse the sequence of slideDown and Up and repeat the movement in a loop.

Since it uses the load() method, the code won't work here, but I am putting the code I am using anyway so you can check the logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.show-project-01').on('click', function(){         

        if ($('.project').html() == "") {   
            $('.project').slideDown()
            $('.project').load('project-01.html')
        } else {
            $('.project').slideUp()
            $('.project').empty()
        }

        return false
            
        }) 
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="title-project show-project-01">Pure office <img src="assets/teste-01.jpg" alt="" class="image-01"></a>

<div class="project">
</div>
```

I am new to jquery, so I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong and any suggestion is more than welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use data attributes to make sure the container div is open or closed

```
var button = $('.show-project-01');
var container = $('.project');  

// add data-open attribute of close
button.attr('data-open','close');
  // on button click
  button.on('click',function() {        

    // get data-open arrtibute 
    var open = $(this).data('open');

    // if data-open is open 
    if(open != 'open'){  
      // update data-open to open
      $(this).data('open','open');
      container.load('project-01.html', function() {
           container.slideDown();
      });     
 } else {
        container.slideUp();
        // do you need to remove the html?
        //container.empty()
        // update data-open to close
        $(this).data('open','close');
    }
});
```

working example - https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/Lp2r3yqn/

Comment: Thank you for the help! It is working on that specific case, however, I have several other toggle() and slideDown() / slideUp() functions for other items on the menu that just go "crazy" once I first activate the code you have provided. I believe it has something to do with the "data-open" attribute, but I don't know why or how to prevent this from happening...

Comment: please can you add another question with all of the code so i can have a look.

Comment: Thank you, Jim-miraidev! I have figured out the problem. As I was loading an html into another html, it was also loading twice the same jquery functions and that's why it was duplicating all actions. ;)

Comment: awesome! glad i could help you resolve your issue :)